# Delete records from postgres from databricks. (pyspark)

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, databricks

So i am using pyspark to connect to postgres database from databricks, i can read , i can create table and also update it. but i am unable to delete a record.

```
dfs = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
.option("url", jdbcUrl)\
.option("user", user)\
.option("password", password)\
.option("query", "DELETE FROM meta.test4 WHERE Emp_Id = 1")\
.load()
```

this snippet here results in a syntax error
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"`

How do i delete a record in postgres?

Comment: I had same issue of not being able to delete so I went with read into df->filter->overwrite existing table way as table overwrite was supported in my case

Answer (score 0):

`spark.read` is only used for reading data. Internally, it wraps the query in a `SELECT * FROM (<query>)` so your statement actually becomes:

`SELECT * FROM (DELETE FROM meta.test4 WHERE Emp_Id = 1)`

and this obviously causes syntax error as you described.

If you want to run DML/DDL operations against remote database, you need to explicitly connect and run a statement using JDBC's `Connection` and `Statement` classes. [This tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-jdbc/insert/) provides a nice overview.