# Issues with Deleting Data and Appending to a PostgreSQL Table in Databricks using PySpark

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, databricks, databricks-sql

I am encountering difficulties in my Databricks PySpark code while trying to delete specific data from a PostgreSQL table and then append new data to it. The issue seems to be related to the table or view not being found, despite my attempts to create the schema and table dynamically.

## Define the widget for schema name and invoice number

dbutils.widgets.text("schema_name_widget", "test")
dbutils.widgets.text("invoice_number_widget", "12345")

## Get the schema name and invoice number from the widgets

schema_name = dbutils.widgets.get("schema_name_widget")
invoice_number = dbutils.widgets.get("invoice_number_widget")

## Full table name with schema

table_name = "intake_invoice_shiprocket"
full_table_name = f"{schema_name}.{table_name}"

## Condition for deletion

condition = f"invoice_number = '{invoice_number}'"

## Execute the delete query using spark.sql

delete_query = f"DELETE FROM {full_table_name} WHERE {condition}"
spark.sql(delete_query)

## Write data to PostgreSQL

invoice_data.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=full_table_name, mode="append", properties=connection_properties)

Comment: Please share the exact error message you are receiving because it is not clear at which step the error is occurring. `spark.sql(delete_query)` is supposed to delete from a spark table and will not have connection to the PostgreSQL Table right ? There is a linked tutorial in the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72527180/delete-records-from-postgres-from-databricks-pyspark) - Refer to it and use it at your own risk after validation...